# 403 forbidden with HttpWebRequest Class

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-403

Dear all,
I encountered 403 forbidden message when I try to get web image by HttpWebRequest Class.
my code is listed below. How can I solve it ? Thanks !

```
public void getWebData()
    {
        string url = "http://www.bijint.com/hokkaido/tokei_images/HHMM.jpg";
        /*****  "HH" stands for hour of current time and "MM" for minute  *****/
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;
        BinaryReader binaryReader = null;
        FileStream outputFile = null;
        BinaryWriter binaryWriter = null;
        StreamReader streamReader = null;

        try
        {
            httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; zh-TW; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 GTB7.1 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

            httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            string httpContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            listBox1.Items.Add(httpContent);
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Exception occurred on request: " + wex.Message);
            if (wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wex.Response;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (httpWebResponse != null)
                httpWebResponse.Close();
            if (binaryReader != null)
                binaryReader.Close();
            if (streamReader != null)
                streamReader.Close();
            if (outputFile != null)
                outputFile.Close();
            if (binaryWriter != null)
                binaryWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: VinayC is mostly correct, but you'll have to refer to the content provider to resolve (either by allowing anonymous access or by supplying you with credentials you can implement).

Answer (score 1):

The said url http://www.bijint.com/hokkaido/tokei_images/HHMM.jpg gives same 403 error when invoked from browser - it simply means that the said resource is secured on the web server and one must supply some credentials to access it. You need to get this information (what kind of credentials are required) and then update your code to pass same credentials.

Comment: No, you're thinking of a 401 - 403 means his credentials are no good, although of course the server could always be misrepresenting this, and the lack of credentials in the OPs code suggests that the practical solution is just to find and supply explicit credentials.

Comment: In firefox, if "http://www.bijint.com/hokkaido/" was visited first, then "http://www.bijint.com/hokkaido/tokei_images/HHMM.jpg" could be access. By the way, "HH" stands for hour of current time and "MM" for minute

Comment: @Daniel - experimenting with, it appears that only image for current time can be accessed via this URL. You will get 403 for all other image urls - my guess is that other images may be getting deleted or there is any active script that is generating image based on current time. In either case, you have to contact content provider.